# Going from 72V to 5V with multiple switching regulators

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I have a 72V battery which I want to step down to a 5V controller with limited power loss. The problem is that looking on the TI website the biggest range I could find for power regulators is the LMZ36002 which will take a maximum of 60V. How can I use this for my application? Can I put two of these in series? Is there a way I can split the work or some devices Ive missed to do this?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There are designs that make use of mains voltages, look at how they are implemented.    -    https://www.google.com/search?q=72V+to+5V+DC/DC+schematic&tbm=isch

Comment: There are buck converters with even 100 V max input voltage, have a look again http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/step-down-buck-products.page#

Comment: [LM5576 
SIMPLE SWITCHER® 6V to 75V, 3A Wide Vin Step-Down Regulator](http://www.ti.com/product/lm5576)

Comment: All design specs must include Min Max inputV and output CUrrent

Comment: VIper 12AS in buck configuration!

Comment: Why not use discrete components ? There are P chan Fets which will give you a simple circuit if your current is not huge      . Si Shottky diodes are easy to find at 100 or 200 V.A buck convertor will work .When the ratio of V in to V out is high there is more to be gained by employing some switching loss reduction scheme.

Comment: Although buck converters could certainly be used, it might make more sense to use a transformer-based converter like a [flyback converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) since the duty cycle becomes absurdly small at high conversion ratios (about 7% on, 93% off in your case). A low duty cycle will lead to high peak currents and lower the efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the LM5017: -

[image]

It can do load currents up to 600 mA. There's also the LT8303: -

[image]

This has an isolated output.

> Can I put two of these in series?

You can stack switchers in series. For instance, you could use the LM5017 to drop to below 60 V (say 50 V) then use the LMZ36002 to finally convert to 5 V allowing you to get the full 2 A from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller with an external switch so you can regulate the smps input voltage with a separate zener diode for example.

Comment: The author requests _"with limited power loss"_. A zener diode isn't very useful here.

Comment: @pipe power drain of the switching controller is usually max tens of milliamps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put two in series to split up the input voltage to get below the converters' maximum rating: That doesn't work. With linear regulators, the "GND" pin is only voltage reference and it is possible to shift that with resistors and/or zener diodes, but with a buck converter that's drawing current from GND in the "off" phase this is not possible that easily. Sinking so much current from above would disturb the lower converter greatly, and the setup would blow up in the startup phase anyway.